# calling child method in parent component

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I have two components. One is Parent and second is child.

What I want to do is Add new element in child component(for now it is simple div).

It is working when I click button (Add pallet) in child html.

When I click the button (Add pallet) on parent HTML it's not working.

It's creating a new instance of pallets but this div doesn't show on child HTML. Result in console.log is the same.

**Child component:**

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import { Pallet } from '../pallet.model';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-workspace',
  templateUrl: './workspace.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./workspace.component.css']

})

export class WorkspaceComponent  {
  pallets: Pallet[] = [];

addPallet1(){

  let temp = new Pallet();
  temp.palletName = 'Pallet'+(this.pallets.length+1);
  temp.id=(this.pallets.length+1).toString();
  temp.width = "500";
  this.pallets.push(temp);
  console.log(temp); /*=>> 

Pallet {palletName: "Pallet1", id: "1", width: "500"}
id: "1"
palletName: "Pallet1"
width: "500"
__proto__: Object

*/

}
ngOnInit(){}
```

**Child HTML:**

```
<div id="workspace" class="workspace">
   <div class="workspace-box" cdkDrag >

    <button (click) = "addPallet1()">Add Pallet</button> 
<button (click) = "check()">check</button>
    <div class="pallet" *ngFor="let pallet of pallets; let index=index" cdkDrag [ngStyle]="{'width.px': pallet.width }">

      <div
      [(ngModel)]="pallet.palletName"
      name="{{pallet.palletName}}"
      id="{{pallet.id}}"
      ngDefaultControl>
        <label>{{pallet.palletName}}</label>        
      </div>      
    </div>
  <div>
```

parent html:

```
<button (click)="appChildWorkspace.addPallet1()">Add Pallet</button>
<app-workspace #appChildWorkspace></app-workspace>
```

Comment: try switching changeDetection strategy to onPush on a child component.

Comment: I recognize that every click on parent creates a new instance of pallet but this new div doesn't show on child html. Then when I press a button on child component, all of these instances show up

Comment: it's working for me. Check the [link](https://plnkr.co/edit/X45uR9690X12aVVO?open=lib%2Fapp.ts&deferRun=1)

Comment: I don't know why it's not working for me. Here is github repository: https://github.com/krystiangit/angular-palletizer2.git  there is one button in center of screen which is working fine. There is also button "add test" in side navbar which is in parent module. this button works only if I press first button at the beginning